# Error handling in Doctrine DBAL with comparison to PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, exception, doctrine-orm, dbal

With PDO we have [`\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), and with setting it to `\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` we are able to get detailed exception stack trace ([`getTrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php)).

How it's with DBAL? How to set in DBAL level of how it throw errors?

DBAL is a wrapper around the PDO instance, with DBAL most methods of PDO work the same, is there also `ATTR_ERRMODE` or some other similar reporting control method?

I want to use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to better control how errors behave and with `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` level it was very useful.

In PDO:

```php
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$_SESSION['options']['host'].';port='.$_SESSION['options']['port'].';dbname='.$_SESSION['options']['dbname'].';charset='.$_SESSION['options']['charset'];
try {
    $conn = new \PDO($dsn, $_SESSION['options']['user'], $_SESSION['options']['pass']);
    $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // how to set this line in DBAL?
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

The same in DBAL:

```php
<?php
require_once "lib/autoload.php";
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$params = array(
    'dbname' => $_SESSION['options']['dbname'],
    'user' => $_SESSION['options']['user'],
    'password' => $_SESSION['options']['pass'],
    'host' => $_SESSION['options']['host'],
    'port' => $_SESSION['options']['port'],
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => $_SESSION['options']['charset'],
);
try {
    $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

Doctrine DBAL version: 2.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How DBAL throws errors**

I checked and it looks, that DBAL for PDO related drivers, by default sets `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` ([here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.1/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php#L45) and [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.1/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php#L150)), so we have detailed stack trace like in PDO.

In fact DBAL exception, is even little more detailed than PDO - DBAL adds some info to the description of the error (for example [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.1/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php#L109)).

**Options to change level of errors**

It seems, that DBAL lacks feature to change level of how it throw errors.
There is no way to change `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` or `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`.
In theory, it should be available by [driverOptions option](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#custom-driver-options), something like this:

```php
$params = array(
    'dbname' => $options['dbname'],
    'user' => $options['user'],
    'password' => $options['pass'],
    'host' => $options['host'],
    'port' => $options['port'],
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => $options['charset'],
    'driverOptions' => array(
        3 => 0 //here "3" is value of constant ATTR_ERRMODE, and "0" value of constant ERRMODE_SILENT
    )
);
```

It would work, but soon after connection declaration, DBAL overwrites `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` ([here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.1/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php#L45)).
Within PDO there is also `setAttribute` method, with it we would be able to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`, but unfortunately DBAL do not implement `setAttribute` method.

**How to control errors in DBAL**

In DBAL we already have the best level of errors, we can catch everything and to better control we can use `set_error_handler`:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Error handler
 *
 * @param int $err_code the numeric error code
 * @param str $err_str description of the error
 * @param str $err_file the name of the file that contains the error
 * @param int $err_line the line number of the error
 * @param str $err_context details of the error
 */

function errorHandler($err_code, $err_str, $err_file, $err_line, $err_context) {
global $_SESSION;
    $_SESSION['errorCounter']++;
    $error_types = array (
        E_WARNING           => 'WARNING',
        E_NOTICE            => 'NOTICE',
        E_USER_ERROR        => 'USER ERROR',
        E_USER_WARNING      => 'USER WARNING',
        E_USER_NOTICE       => 'USER NOTICE',
        E_STRICT            => 'STRICT',
        E_DEPRECATED        => 'DEPRECATED',
        E_USER_DEPRECATED   => 'USER DEPRECATED'
    );
    $error_type = isset($error_types[$err_code]) ? $error_types[$err_code] : 'UNKNOWN ERROR TYPE['.$err_code.']';
    $err = "\n>--------------------------------------------------------------------";
    $err .= "\n".'EXCEPTION #'.$_SESSION['errorCounter'].':';
    $err .= "\n\n---- PHP ".$error_type.": ----";
    $err .= "\n".$err_str;

    //$err .= print_r($err_context, 1);
    if (isset($err_context['e'])){
        $err .= "\n\n---- STACKTRACE: ----";
        $dir_root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
        $err .=  "\nroot: " . $dir_root;
        foreach ($err_context['e']->getTrace() as $a => $b) {
            $err .= "\n" . strval($a) . '# ';
            foreach ($b as $c => $d) {
                switch($c){
                    case 'file':
                        $err .=  str_replace($dir_root,'(root)',str_replace('\\','/',$d));
                        break;
                    case 'line':
                        $err .=  '(' . $d . "); ";
                        break;
                    case 'function':
                        $err .=  $c . ' ' . $d . "; ";
                        break;
                    case 'class':
                        $err .=  $c . ' ' . $d . "; ";
                        break;
                    case 'type':
                        $err .=  $c . ': ' . $d . "; ";
                        break;
                    case 'args':
                        foreach ($d as $e => $f){
                            $e = is_object($e) ? 'object' : is_array($e) ? 'array' : trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $e));//do not return objects, arrays and change new lines to space
                            $f = is_object($f) ? 'object' : is_array($f) ? 'array' : trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $f));//do not return objects, arrays and change new lines to space
                            $err .= 'args-' . $e . ': ' . $f . '; ';
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $err .= "\n\n---- LOCATION: ----";
        $err .= "\n".$err_file.'(' . $err_line . ')';
    }

    $err .= "\n\n---- CONNECTION: ----";
    $err .= "\n".'host: '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $err .= "\n".'client: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $err .= "\n".'timestamp: '.date("d-m-Y h:i:s A");
    $err .= "\n<--------------------------------------------------------------------\n";



    if (ini_get('log_errors')) {
        error_log($err, 0);
        if($err_code == E_USER_ERROR) {
            if (!$_SESSION['options']['debug']) {
                //send email with error
            }
        }
    }

    if ($_SESSION['options']['debug'])
        print("\n<pre>".$err."</pre>\n");

    return true;
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler");
```